# Determining if a file is media playable

Tags: c++, mfc, createprocess, ffprobe

I am seeking a tool with which I can use with the MFC CreateProcess() command to determine whether a file is media playable file or not.  I am not permitted to compare file extension with an 'allowable' set such as mp3, mp4, avi etc - it has to be done deterministically with tools such as ffprobe, DirectShow.

I have experimented with ffprobe which when applied to media files gives certain information such as start time, duration, codec name, format name etc.  All this is usually very useful when I need to exclude non-playables such as text files, Word documents etc.

Unfortunately ffprobe sometimes returns information suggesting that the file I pass to it is media playable when it is not.  For example a Windows .dmp file is returning a MP3 codec_name!

Is anyone aware of other strategies I could use in order to determine a file's media-playability?

Comment: What is the higher-level problem you're trying to solve?  What is the definition of "playable?"  Playable assuming codecs are installed?  Playable using only the codecs already installed?  Playable if DRM constraints are met?  Or disregarding DRM constraints?

Comment: Sorry it's a little vague on that front.  "Playable using only the codecs already installed" would probably be the most appropriate.